# Finding the upper bound for the following function. (Complex numbers involved)

Tags: complex-numbers

We are supposed to find an upper bound on :

$E=|z_1-z_2|^2+|z_2-z_3|^2+|z_3-z_1|^2$ where $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are unimodular complex numbers, i.e $|z_i|=1$.

Let us take the first term : $|z_1-z_2|^2$

$|z_1-z_2|^2=(z_1-z_2)(\bar{z_1}-\bar{z_2})=|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2-z_1\bar{z_2}-\bar{z_1}z_2=|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2-2Re(z_1\bar{z_2})$

Taking : $z_j=e^{i\theta_j}$, hence $z_1\bar{z_2}=e^{i\theta_1}e^{-i\theta_2}=e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}=\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)+i\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)$.

So, $Re(z_1\bar{z_2})=\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$.

Now, $\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)\geq(-1)$ i.e. $Re(z_1\bar{z_2})\geq(-1)$ = $(-2)Re(z_1\bar{z_2})\leq2$, thus,

$|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+(-2)Re(z_1\bar{z_2})\leq2 + |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2$

Hence,

$|z_1-z_2|^2\leq 4$

Similarly, for second and third term, so we have :

$E\leq 12$

But the solution says $9$, What did I do wrong ? Can any one help ?

Comment: I get 12 too.  From your set up we get: $E=|z_1-z_2|^2+|z_2-z_3|^2+|z_3-z_1|^2 = |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 - 2Re(z_1\bar{z_2}) + |z_2|^2 + |z_3|^2 - 2Re(z_2\bar{z_3}) + |z_3|^2 + |z_1|^2 - 2Re(z_3\bar{z_1}).$   Because $|z_i|=1$, then $E=6 - 2(Re(z_1\bar{z_2}) + Re(z_2\bar{z_3}) + Re(z_3\bar{z_1})).$     As you pointed out, $Re(z_i\bar{z_k}) \in [-1,1]$ and so we get the minimum value for $Re(z_1\bar{z_2}) + Re(z_2\bar{z_3}) + Re(z_3\bar{z_1}) = -3.$  Thus, $E \leq 6 - 2(-3) = 12$

Comment: The maximum is not $12$. To get a distance-squared of $4$, the pair of points would have to be diametrically opposite on the unit circle. But all $3$ pairs can't be diametrically opposite.

Comment: Note that if $z_1,z_2,z_3$ on the unit circle are points of an equilateral triangle, then the sum of the squared distances is exactly $9$. Thus, I would try to argue that of all triangles inscribed in the unit circle, the equilateral triangle has the greatest sum of squares of side lengths.

Comment: I get that point of yours and was able to prove it also that to get a distance-squared of $4$ they'll have to be at an angle of $\pi$, but I've checked my solution above many times but I can't find the step where I went wrong, the upper bound I got above is 'bad' I accept, but I can't find where the problem lies.. @quasi

Comment: @User9523: $12$ is an upper bound ($4+4+4$), but not the least upper bound. The distances are not independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that  $$|\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)+\cos(\theta_2-\theta_3)+\cos(\theta_3-\theta_1)|\le \frac {3}{2}$$ because $z_1,z_2$,and $z_3$ are on the unit circle.

That should solve your problem with your upper bound.

Comment: How can we prove that inequality ? Some hints ?

Comment: @User9523 The sum of angles is 0 now you can use Lagrange multiplier to find the maximum absolute  values  of sum of cosines subject to the given constraint.